# Syntactical proof in a Hilbert system without additional lemmas

Tags: propositional-calculus, hilbert-calculus

How do I proof $\neg \neg p \rightarrow p$ in the following Hilbert system without the use of additional lemmas (derive purely syntactical)?

1. $A \rightarrow (B \rightarrow C)$
2. $(A \rightarrow (B \rightarrow C)) \rightarrow ((A \rightarrow B) \rightarrow (A \rightarrow C))$
3. $(\neg A \rightarrow \neg B) \rightarrow ((\neg A \rightarrow B) \rightarrow A)$

In [Logic in action](http://www.logicinaction.org/) there is a proof for $p \rightarrow p$, which is easy to grasp (pdf-version of the textbook onchapter 2 page 23) and in [this pdf file](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=2ahUKEwju17r2wProAhUBwAIHHTmzDdcQFjAAegQIAxAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww3.cs.stonybrook.edu%2F~cse541%2Fchapter8.pdf&usg=AOvVaw19FFUKWsnnuLnhHy0WqzFn) (page 12) there is a proof for the exact problem of this question, except that it uses additional lemmas and transformations.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Proof of a theorem in Hilbert's system](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1018185/proof-of-a-theorem-in-hilberts-system) It is enough to copy-paste the "Lemma" into a single derivation: they are not necessary, but used only to improve readibility.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reference! I am not quite sure where ¬β→¬¬β comes from in the derivation of Lemma 1? (which would pretty much answer the question, but I cant make sense of "assumed [a]" right next to it either)

Comment: Ah, I got it now, thank you very much!

Comment: You are welcome :-)