# Hilbert Calculus statement proof

Tags: logic, hilbert-calculus

I want to prove in $HPC$ that

$$ \vdash_{HPC} (A\rightarrow B)\rightarrow ((B\rightarrow C) \rightarrow (A\rightarrow C ))$$

I tried using different combinations of the $A\rightarrow (B \rightarrow A)$ and 
$ (A \rightarrow (B \rightarrow C)) \rightarrow ((A \rightarrow B) \rightarrow (A \rightarrow C)) $ axioms but didn't reach the result. What am I missing?

thanks.

Comment: Are you interested in a proof in HPC without using deduction theorem?

Comment: Yes, if it's not too much of a bother.

Comment: See the related post [proof-of-transitivity-in-hilbert-style](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/290725/proof-of-transitivity-in-hilbert-style)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

Using the deduction theorem for $HPC$, this is correct iff:
$$ A\rightarrow B, B \rightarrow C, A \vdash_{HPC} C$$

which is easily proven by using the $MP$ rule 2 times.

Comment: And if you really want to avoid the deduction theorem, then take this "MP twice" proof and run it through the proof of the deduction theorem.

Comment: @AndreasBlass As often holds, I don't think that's very efficient for producing an axiomatic proof of a relatively small size.  If you do that, is the proof, including the axioms, more than 16 steps?

Comment: @DougSpoonwood The length of the proof would depend on the details of the axiom system. For example, $X\to X$ would be a reasonable axiom, but it can also be proved in 5 lines from the axiom schemes explicitly mentioned in the question. With just these two axiom schemes, I'd expect a direct application of the proof of the deduction theorem to take somewhat more than 16 lines, because the deduction theorem is applied 3 times. The advantage of this method would not be in the brevity of the resulting proof but in not needing any intelligence to find it.

Comment: @AndreasBlass I've studied some different axiom sets for what might get called the intuitionistic implicational propositional calculus (in significant measure by reading Dolph Ulrich's work here and associated work: https://web.ics.purdue.edu/~dulrich/C-pure-intuitionism-page.htm.)  I have NOT seen any set of independent axioms where (X$\rightarrow$X) is an axiom as opposed to being a theorem.  If you know of any such axiom sets that perhaps might be of interest.  I'm not sure that the literature has such an axiom set in it.

Answer (score 0):

I use Polish notation.  This means that well-formed formulas get re-defined such that every wff of the form ($\alpha$$\rightarrow$$\beta$) gets translated to C$\alpha$$\beta$.  I don't spell out the substitutions made in the below, but I use spacing to show that a substitution follows the form of the axiom.  The basic idea runs as follows: we prove CCbcCCabCac and then change the positions of 'Cbc' and 'Cab'.

```
1. CaCba axiom 
2. CCaCbcCCabCac axiom 
3. C CCaCbcCCabCac C Cbc CCaCbcCCabCac 1
4. CCbcCCaCbcCCabCac 3, 2
5. CC Cbc C CaCbc CCabCac CC Cbc CaCbc C Cbc CCabCac 2
6. CCCbcCaCbcCCbcCCabCac 5, 4
7. C Cbc C a Cbc 1
8. CCbcCCabCac 6, 7
9. CC Cbc C Cab Cac CC Cbc Cab C Cbc Cac 2
10. CCCbcCabCCbcCac 9, 8
11. C CCCbcCabCCbcCac C Cab CCCbcCabCCbcCac 2
12. CCabCCCbcCabCCbcCac 11, 10
13. CC Cab C CCbcCab CCbcCac CC Cab CCbcCab C Cab CCbcCac 2
14. CCCabCCbcCabCCabCCbcCac 13, 12
15. C Cab C Cbc Cab 1
16. CCabCCbcCac 14, 15
```